# Slowdown querying Sharepoint using SQL from

Tags: sql, .net

We've currently got an Access database we use to update a sharepoint list.
It works, but I'm trying to convert it to a Windows App to make it a bit nicer.

I've got some of the stuff worked out but I've come across a snag.

I've got two comboboxes that I get the options for using a SQL script that's built and then run against the sharepoint database.

These work fine.

The problem comes when I make a selection from the 2nd combobox that's then supposed to bring back some extra fields for the user to edit as necessary.

It takes forever (and uses a ton of CPU).  In fact, I've had to kill it in Task Manager to get it to stop.
The odd thing is, when I run the same query in the Access databases that the 2nd combobox generates (I've stepped through the query to make sure I haven't made any stupid syntax errors), it brings back the info in less than a second.

Here's my code so far (I've redacted part of the connection string):-

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form1
    Dim sqlQuery As String, sqlAddon As String
    Dim Title As String, Comments As String, Actions As String, LeadDeveloper As String
    Dim RequestedDate As Date, TargetDate As Date
    Dim dt As DataTable, myDataTable As DataTable
    Dim cont As Boolean
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'Load the Teams dropdown when opening the form
        GetTeams()
    End Sub
    Private Sub btn_Exit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Exit.Click
        'Neatly close down the form when exiting
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
    Private Sub btn_Go_First_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Go_First.Click
        'Change the selected index to 0
        cb_Title.SelectedIndex = 0
    End Sub
    Private Sub btn_Go_Previous_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Go_Previous.Click
        If cb_Title.SelectedIndex > 0 Then
            cb_Title.SelectedIndex = cb_Title.SelectedIndex - 1
        Else
            MsgBox("You are already at the first record", vbOKOnly, "XXX Error XXX")
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub btn_Go_Next_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Go_Next.Click
        If cb_Title.SelectedIndex < cb_Title.Items.Count - 1 Then
            cb_Title.SelectedIndex = cb_Title.SelectedIndex + 1
        Else
            MsgBox("You are already at the last record", vbOKOnly, "XXX Error XXX")
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub btn_Go_Last_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Go_Last.Click
        cb_Title.SelectedIndex = cb_Title.Items.Count - 1
    End Sub
    Private Sub cb_TeamName_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cb_TeamName.SelectedIndexChanged
        'Check to see if this is when the form has been opened
        'If it is, cont will be false so don't do anything
        If cont = True Then
            cont = False
            'Check to see if the "Include Closed" box has been ticked
            'If it has, grab them all
            If ck_Closed.Checked = True Then
                sqlAddon = ""
            Else
                sqlAddon = "AND [HI WorkProgramme].Closed = 0"
            End If
            'Set up the SQL query ready for running
            sqlQuery = "SELECT Heading FROM [HI WorkProgramme] WHERE [Team Name] = '" & cb_TeamName.Text & "' " & sqlAddon & " ORDER BY Heading;"
            'Now get the data from Sharepoint
            dt = FilledTable(sqlQuery)
            'Assign the data to the combobox
            cb_Title.DisplayMember = dt.Columns(0).ToString
            cb_Title.ValueMember = dt.Columns(0).ToString
            cb_Title.SelectedValue = ""
            cb_Title.DataSource = dt
            'Reset the boolean variable
            cont = True
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub ck_Closed_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ck_Closed.CheckedChanged
        'Check to see if the tick-box has changed and reload the headings
        cb_TeamName_SelectedIndexChanged(sender, e)
    End Sub
    Private Sub cb_Title_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cb_Title.SelectedIndexChanged
        'Exit Sub
        'Check to see if this is when the form has been opened
        'If it is, cont will be false so don't do anything
        If cont = True Then
            'Set up the SQL query ready for interrogating Sharepoint
            'First make sure it's clear
            sqlQuery = ""
            'No build the query
            sqlQuery = "SELECT [HI WorkProgramme].[Action],[HI WorkProgramme].[Update],[HI WorkProgramme].[Date Added],[HI WorkProgramme].[Lead]" '[UserInfo].[Name]" '
            sqlQuery = sqlQuery & ",[HI WorkProgramme].[Target date Completion] "
            sqlQuery = sqlQuery & " FROM [HI WorkProgramme] INNER JOIN [UserInfo] ON [UserInfo].[ID] = [HI WorkProgramme].[Lead] "
            sqlQuery = sqlQuery & "WHERE [HI WorkProgramme].[Team Name] = '" & cb_TeamName.Text & "' AND [HI WorkProgramme].[Heading] = '" & cb_Title.Text & "'"
            'Now grab the data
            dt = FilledTable(sqlQuery)
            'Assign the data to internal variables ready for pushing into the various on-screen boxes
            txtAction.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(0).ToString
            txtUpdate.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(1).ToString
            RequestedDate = dt.Rows(0).Item(2).ToString
            LeadDeveloper = dt.Rows(0).Item(3).ToString
            TargetDate = dt.Rows(0).Item(4).ToString
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub GetTeams()
        'Make sure we don't get into a loop when loading the teams
        cont = False
        'Set up the SQL ready for getting data from Sharepoint
        'First make sure it's clear
        sqlQuery = ""
        'Now build the query
        sqlQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT [Team Name] FROM [HI WorkProgramme];"
        'Now get the data from Sharepoint
        dt = FilledTable(sqlQuery)
        'Assign the data to the Teams combobox
        cb_TeamName.DisplayMember = dt.Columns(0).ToString
        cb_TeamName.ValueMember = dt.Columns(0).ToString
        cb_TeamName.SelectedValue = ""
        cb_TeamName.DataSource = dt
        'Reset the boolean so that changing the team ctually does something
        cont = True
    End Sub
    Public Function FilledTable(ByVal sql As String) As DataTable
        'This the function tat actually gets the data from Sharepoint
        Using con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;WSS;IMEX=2;RetrieveIds=Yes;DATABASE=SharepointDatabase")
            Using command As New OleDbCommand(sql, con)
                con.Open()
                Using dr As OleDb.OleDbDataReader = command.ExecuteReader
                    Using myDataTable As New DataTable
                        Try
                            myDataTable.Clear()
                            myDataTable.Load(dr)
                            Return myDataTable
                        Catch ex As Exception
                            Return Nothing
                        End Try
                        myDataTable.Dispose()
                    End Using
                End Using
                con.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Function
End Class
```

Has anyone got any insights why the code suddenly slows down when I make a selection from the 2nd combobox (cb_Title)?
Just to add, I'm new to this (maybe not the best project to cut my teeth on) so any tips/best practice suggestions/improvement ideas would also be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Richard

Comment: maybe ms access database doesn't scale really well. try adding index on columns that you put in ```WHERE``` and ```ORDER BY``` clause

Comment: The access database works fine.  I'm trying to convert it to a Windows App.  The query works fine in Access, it's just when I run it from the Windows App that it runs really slowly (if it ever finishes)